# Why does my process spawn four times, instead of two?

Tags: python, python-2.7, process, multiprocessing

I have three scripts, Python 2.7.9 (kivy) on Win7x64.

**multiprocessing_1**

```
def Multiprocessing_3():
    print "Hohoo!"
    import multiprocessing_3
    multiprocessing_3.LetseGo()

print "It'se me,",__name__," !!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import multiprocessing_2
    multiprocessing_2.main()
```

---

**multiprocessing_2**

```
import multiprocessing

def main():
    print "YA!"
    import multiprocessing_1
    Multiprocessing3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=multiprocessing_1.Multiprocessing_3,args=(''))
    Multiprocessing3.start()
```

---

**multiprocessing_3**

```
def LetseGo():
    print "YAHoooooooo!"
```

My question is about the output I get thrown at, after executing `python multiprocessing_1.py`:

```
It'se me, __main__!!
YA!
It'se me, multiprocessing_1!!
It'se me, __parents_main__!!
It'se me, multiprocessing_1!!
Hohoo!
YAHoooooooo!
```

Or see the output here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8anvL.png

`_1` starts as `__main__`, then imports and calls `_2`, which then spawns the process `_1.Multiprocessing_3`, which imports and executes `_3.LetseGo()`.

What is happening, though, is that `_1` actually runs *four* times, instead of the two I actually expected.

Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you're running the code on Windows, and Windows needs to [re-import your `__main__` module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#windows) (which happens to be `multiprocessing_1.py`) in the child process in order to execute the function you passed to `multiprocessing.Process`. Additionally, the function you want to call in the child, `Multiprocessing_3`, needs to be pickled in order to send it from the parent process to the child, and unpickling the function in the child requires importing the module that the function belongs to, which again, is `multiprocessing_1`. So the explanation for each output is:

```
It'se me, __main__!!  # multiprocessing_1 is imported when you execute it directly.
YA!
It'se me, multiprocessing_1!!  # multiprocessing_2.py calls 'import multiprocessing_1'
It'se me, __parents_main__!!  # after you call multiprocessing3.start(), the child process needs to re-import the `__main__` module of your script, which is multiprocessing_1.py
It'se me, multiprocessing_1!!  # This import happens so that the Multiprocessing_3 function can be unpickled in the child.
Hohoo!
YAHoooooooo!
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I do understand all, but the last. Why would `_1` need to be re-re-imported into the child, so the child can unpickle `_3` ? It already imported it before! Please excuse an eventual language barrier I might not be aware of.

Comment: @Solecist - when you created a process with `target=multiprocessing_1.Multiprocessing_3`, `multiprocessing_1` needs to be imported to get `Multiprocessing_3` and everything else it may depend on in the module. `pickle` only pickles references to functions. The module itself must be available and importable by whatever does the unpickling.